# Python Sort and Compare Nested Dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to sort and compare dictionaries that contain lists of dictionaries and other data in `Python 3.6`. I am not sure the best way to compare the two. The data in the two dictionaries is the same, but I can't control the order in which they are given. The data looks like the following:

```
dict_A = {
    'addresses': [
        {'address': 'Tribal Land', 'address_country': 'AB', 'city': None, 'postal_code': None, 'state': 'GY'},
        {'address': 'Userland', 'address_country': 'ND', 'city': None, 'postal_code': None, 'state': 'KY'}],
    'name': 'FooBar', 
    'dob': None, 
    'ids':[
        {'date': None, 'country': None, 'number': 'Male', 'type': 'Gender', 'location': 'USA'},
        {'date': None, 'country': 'VE', 'number': '1234567', 'type': 'Foo No.', 'location': 'USA'}]
}


dict_B = {
    'addresses': [
        {'address': 'Userland', 'address_country': 'ND', 'city': None, 'postal_code': None, 'state': 'KY'},
        {'address': 'Tribal Land', 'address_country': 'AB', 'city': None, 'postal_code': None, 'state': 'GY'}],
    'dob': None, 
    'id':[
        {'country': 'VE', 'date': None, 'type': 'Foo No.', 'location': 'USA', 'number': '1234567'},
        {'country': None, 'date': None, 'type': 'Gender', 'location': 'USA', 'number': 'Male'}],
    'name': 'FooBar'
}
```

I am trying to do get a comparison with `dict_A == dict_B` evaluating to `True`.

I have tried to loop through the dictionary, send the items to Pandas and set the `dict` to `ordered_dict`, but that doesn't seem to work. I am not sure on the best approach to this.

```
        # Loop over data, and conver the list of dicts to data frame for sorting,
            # then take the data, once sorted, and put it back into list of dicts
            for key, val in dict_A.items():
                if type(val) is list:
                    val.sort(key=lambda x: x if isinstance(x, str) else "")
                    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(val, index=range(len(val)))
                    dataframe.sort_values(by=dataframe.columns[0])
                    new_val = [OrderedDict(row) for i, row in dataframe.iterrows()]
                    dict_A.update({key: new_val})
```

Perhaps would the better way be to set the dictionaries to lists, and compare it that way?

Comment: The key/value pairs do not make a lot of sense: `'number': 'Male'`, `'type': 'Gender'`, `'country': None`, `'location': 'USA'`.

Comment: Possibly random data he made on the spot? I'd suggest [Mockaroo](http://www.mockaroo.com/) for that kind of thing.

Comment: @srig, it was contrived data I made up. Ultimately was just for example purpose

Comment: Why are you trying to sort them when you know that the only difference between them is that the lists do not follow an order?

Comment: I want to compare the two data sets. If it was not obvious, the data above is contrived, but the real data I am comparing has a similar structure of nested data. I am comparing a known set of data to an unknown set of data from an API. Sometimes there will be a match, sometimes there will be different data. I need to know when that is.

Answer (score 1):

So if all you have is lists and dictionaries, you can call custom equal methods on each one. For example,

```
def list_equal(l1, l2):
    if type(l1[0]) is dict:
        if len(l1) != len(l2):
            return False
        for i in range(len(l1)):
            if not l1.count(l1[i]) == l2.count(l1[i]):
                 return False
        return True
    return sorted(l1) == sorted(l2)
```

Then

```
def structures_equal(s1, s2):
    if not sorted(list(set(s1.keys()))) == sorted(list(set(s2.keys()))):
        return False
    for key in s1:
        if type(s1[key]) is list:
            if not type(s2[key]) is list:
                return False
            elif not list_equal(s1[key], s2[key]):
                return False
        elif not s1[key] == s2[key]:
            return False
        return True
```

Right now the list comparisons run in O(n^2) because it counts the instances of each row. If you are getting these rows from the same data source, it would be useful to pull a Unique ID for each one as well. Timing then becomes significantly faster because we only compare the UIDS and their counts in each list. Even more good if you can make this a dictionary of UIDS and the number of instances of the rows assigned. For example

```
[{'address': 'address0', 'foo': 'bar0', 'uid': 0},
 {'address': 'address1', 'foo': 'bar1', 'uid': 1},
 {'address': 'address2', 'foo': 'bar2', 'uid': 2},
 {'address': 'address3', 'foo': 'bar3', 'uid': 3},
 {'address': 'address4', 'foo': 'bar4', 'uid': 4},
 {'address': 'address0', 'foo': 'bar0', 'uid': 0},
 {'address': 'address1', 'foo': 'bar1', 'uid': 1},
 {'address': 'address2', 'foo': 'bar2', 'uid': 2}]
```

becomes

```
{0: [{'address': 'address0', 'foo': 'bar0', 'uid': 0},
     {'address': 'address0', 'foo': 'bar0', 'uid': 0}],
 1: [{'address': 'address1', 'foo': 'bar1', 'uid': 1},
     {'address': 'address1', 'foo': 'bar1', 'uid': 1}],
 2: [{'address': 'address2', 'foo': 'bar2', 'uid': 2},
     {'address': 'address2', 'foo': 'bar2', 'uid': 2}],
 3: [{'address': 'address3', 'foo': 'bar3', 'uid': 3}],
 4: [{'address': 'address4', 'foo': 'bar4', 'uid': 4}]}
```

The algorithm for this will then be

```
def list_converted_to_dict_equal(d1, d2):
    for key in d1:
        if key not in d2 or len(d1[key]) != len(d2[key]):
            return False
    return True
```

Which is much better than before.

Comment: I don't have all lists and dictionaries in the top level dictionary. I do have some stand alone string values as well, something like `'name':'foobar'`. Some of these key/val pairs have `None` values such as  `'name': None`

Comment: That's why I added the last `elif` statement for.

Comment: Also, do you have a primary key for dicts within `addresses`, `id` or anything else with dicts within lists?

Comment: No primary key. Just the data itself

Comment: Then this solution should work. Also, please replace id key in dict_b with ids to match dict_a

Answer (score 1):

Convert your dictionaries to a data structure i.e. a real class.

For this class, overload the `__cmp__` method for each object, if you want to be able to sort them.

Overload `__eq__` if you want to be able to tell if two objects are equal.

```
class ApiDto(object):
    def __cmp__ (self, other):
        pass
    def __eq__ (self, other):
        pass

class Address(object):
    def __cmp__ (self, other):
        pass
    def __eq__ (self, other):
        pass

class Id(object):
    def __cmp__ (self, other):
        pass
    def __eq__ (self, other):
        pass
```

Change the dicts to now use the above classes.

Now you can sort and compare as you like without having to deal with handling all the attributes at once.

---

In case it's not obvious at this point, the dict you have will now be an `ApiDto` which has a `name` field, an `addresses` field which is a list of `Address`, an `ids` field which is a list of `Id`, and finally a `dob` field.

When you overload `__cmp__` and `__eq__` methods for `ApiDto`, you will do the same for all the classes, and this will allow you to sort the objects and finally compare them to each other.

Also if you ever need to convert the objects back to a dict, you can call the `__dict__` attribute to give you this

Comment: I'm not quite sure I get what you are suggesting I do here.

Comment: @unseen_damage I tried to expand on the answer a little more.

Comment: Sounds like a bit of overkill for this particular example, no?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, It depends on the extent to which the OP wishes to use these objects. Left to me, I wouldn't be handling raw dicts retrieved from an API like that, especially when they are this complex. I would much rather go the route of combining modularity with encapsulation, so that I'm not scrambling about dealing with each individual component separately.

Comment: @smac89. I'm just saying that it is not a very general solution to the problem OP poses. I agree with you entirely that the data is better off sitting in the specific objects in your model. Then you have complete control, without requiring these generic slow sorting algorithms.

Comment: @smac89. When you put it like that, +1